# Meteor.loginWithPassword returns Error: Incorrect password [403]

Tags: authentication, meteor

I would like to add programmatically few users and login with one of them in my meteor app. I could not find any methods to add users at server side; so I added two buttons at client side to generate users and login with one of them. I can create users (I see them in mogodb) but I cannot login, getting Error: Incorrect password [403]. What I  am missing?
This is client.js code

```
Template.hello.events({
 'click #createUsers': function () {
    console.log("Creating users...");
    var users = [
       { email: "dgra@gmail.com", username: "gra", name: "gra", roles: ['admin'] }
    ];
    _.each(users, function (user) {
        Accounts.createUser({
            email: user.email,
            password: "admin",
            profile: { username: user.username },
            profile: { name: user.name },
            roles: user.roles
        });
    });
},

 'click #logIn': function () {
     console.log("logIn gra...");
    Meteor.loginWithPassword("dgra@gmail.com", "admin", function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("loginError: " + err);
        }
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: Try making your password at least 6 characters long when you create the accounts.

Comment: @landland Longer passwords are always better, but `Accounts.createUser` currently has no password length requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find any methods to add users at server side

You can add users from the server. As the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) point out, `Accounts.createUser` runs anywhere. Here is a working example:

#### server/initialize.js

```
var insertUser = function() {
  var user = {
    email: 'dgra@gmail.com',
    username: 'gra',
    name: 'gra'
  };

  Accounts.createUser({
    username: user.username,
    email: user.email,
    password: 'admin',
    profile: {
      name: user.name
    }
  });
};

Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
    insertUser();
  }
});
```

A few points:

1. You can add only one profile object.
2. `Accounts.createUser` only takes the arguments shown in the docs, so you can't add arbitrary objects.
3. If you are trying to use [roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles), the example there shows the roles being added after the account is created.
4. In the code above, I only add the user if there are no users in the database. This is convenient for testing since the user will automatically be inserted after a `meteor reset` (no button pushing requred).

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did not noticed that ‘Client only’ in the doc about Accounts.createUser() was for the callback only.